# haml doesnt work for form_for? (rails 3.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, haml

there is my code in controller

```
def new
    @user = User.new
  end
```

and there is my code in new.html.haml

```
- if @user.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
        %h2 Form is invalid
        %ul
            -for message in  @user.errors.full_messages
                %li= message
            -
-
%section
    %h1 Sign Up
    -form_for @user do |f|
        %p
            = f.label :email
            %br
            = f.text_field :email
        %p
            = f.label :name
            %br
            = f.text_field  :name
        %p
            = f.label :password
            %br
            = f.text_field :password
        %p
            = f.label :password_confirmation
            %br
            = f.password_field :password_confirmation
        %p.button
            = f.submit
    -
```

When I go to the users/new path I have only "Sign up" on my page i dont have labels and texts fields.
I am new to haml. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: please help, i dont want to use erb)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Haml does work with `form_for`.

Looks like you're writing your Haml incorrectly. Try removing the "closing" dashes. Haml takes care of closing blocks or you.

Looks like you also need to echo the block, it should be:

```
= form_for [...]
```

not

```
- form_for [...]
```

Comment: i deleted "-" in the end of each block but it didnt help, i dont have labels and textfields(

Comment: Updated my answer, please check.

Comment: You **have** to use `=` instead of `-` for block helpers such as `form_tag`. Rails 3 gave you a deprecation warning, Rails 3.1 just doesn't render them.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this:

```
-form_for :user do |f|
```